# What causes a 403 error on a local Azure development environment?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, azure

I have an Azure application that works perfectly on every one of my colleagues machines. On mine, the web application works, but not the azure project, which runs on the local development fabric.

I'm getting a 403 error, which causes a blank page in Chrome. The application_start method gets fired and sets up the routes, but the actual MVC controller never gets called. Again, this works perfect if I run the web application directly. If I use that same azure project and deploy it online, it also works fine.

I've tried repairing visual studio, reinstalling Azure, rebooting, re-fetching source, you name it.

I'm desperate for ideas! What would cause a 403?

Comment: I’ve been spending hours trying to fix this issue. If I simply create a new azure site on my computer and create an ASP.NET application, the default site works perfectly.

If I create a new azure site but use MVC2 instead, the MVC site works by itself, but will not work in the local development fabric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer. Looks like I wasn't the first to be victimized by this:
http://scottdensmore.typepad.com/blog/2010/05/how-a-checkbox-saved-paving-my-machine.html

What's interesting is that I wasn't even using IIS.

Comment: But you _were_ using IIS... that's the key difference.  Running the app under the Windows Azure development environment (and in the cloud) uses IIS, while running directly via Visual Studio does not.

Comment: I stopped IIS and disabled it. Are you 100% sure about that?

Comment: You need IIS for dev fabric. Cloud service projects do not run on the asp.net web server inbuilt in visual studio.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179419.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need IIS for dev fabric. Cloud service projects do not run on the asp.net web server inbuilt in visual studio. [Refer this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179419.aspx).

So any configuration issues in IIS will affect you.