# IIS & IIS Express throwing 403 errors locally for MVC4 Azure app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have a C# MVC4 application that I recently migrated to an Azure web role. I can publish/run the site just fine on the Azure platform, but when I try to run it locally using the Azure development fabric, IIS and IIS Express throw a generic 403 errors.

I tried adding the following to my web.config as I've seen it mentioned in numerous posts but it didn't help. This solution seems like a bit of a sledgehammer approach anyways since it's running ALL requests through the managed pipeline, but still, figured I'd give it a shot.

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

I've verified that I can access the "robots.txt" file in my application root so the server is fired up and pointing to the right place, but it won't serve any of my MVC pages.

I also tried the solution in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273390/what-causes-a-403-error-on-a-local-azure-development-environment). No dice there either.

I've also tried switching my Azure web role to run in IIS instead of IIS Express. I get the same 403 error there. Just to be thorough, I did run **aspnet_regiis -ir** even though other MVC apps running locally (non-Azure) on my machine work just fine.

**EDIT**
So this is interesting...when I hit F5 (my Azure project is my startup project), the Azure Compute/Storage emulators fire up and then my browser opens to `http://127.0.0.1:81/`. This is the URL I get the 403 error at.

However, if I'm using IIS (not Express) and I go to the web site in IIS that Azure created during deployment, right click, "Manage Web Site" and then choose "Browse", it opens the site up at `http://localhost:82/`. Note "localhost" instead of 127.0.0.1 and a port of 82 instead of 81 and **IT WORKS!** I can browse through my site with no problems, hit breakpoints, etc. Now if I try `http://127.0.0.1:82` (using the IP, but port 82) I still get the 403.

Any ideas?

Comment: I remember couple issues with web sites in VS: a) check that firewalls and antiviruses are not blocking some ports (just try to disable them) b) in Project settings go to the Web settings, turn off dynamic ports and check fixed port (and set 82).

Comment: Azure doesn't use the web settings in the standard VS MVC project. It loads the compute instances in the Azure development fabric so the web settings for the MVC project won't have any effect. I have no issues getting to port 81/82, I'm just getting 403 errors once they load.

Comment: By any chance is there any websites in your local iis running on port 81 ?

Comment: @outcoldman, setting fixed port for the web project has no effect on the Compute Emulator. For all of you, check out [this article](http://blogs.staykov.net/2013/05/windows-azure-basicscompute-emulator.html) that explains how exactly does the local emulator works and why ports may differ. The only viable suggestion is to check if there is something already listening on socket 127.0.0.1:81, and by some chance VS Tooling is fooled and launches browser on that port, instead of 82.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get exact question you are asking, but I can try to explain why your sites behave this way (we have very similar behaviour at our project). I'm not sure it's 100% correct explanation of this behaviour but I ha
AFAIK:
1. Your IIS and IIS Express can't use same port simultaneously.
2. Azure Compute Emulator running it's own stack\Load balancing proxy ( to emulate multi-instance azure environment) and need to register itself on some port.

So why this stuff happens :
You, probably have some other sites in your IIS, that using port 80. So when Emulator starting - it discovers that port 80 can't be used ( cause it's locked by your working iis). An it starts port-walking, until it find next free port to bind to (for us it'll be 81 and 444). You can check General Output window after starting F5 and you can find similar messages there:

```
Windows Azure Tools: Warning: Remapping public port 80 to 81 to avoid conflict during emulation.
Windows Azure Tools: Warning: Remapping public port 443 to 444 to avoid conflict during emulation.
Windows Azure Tools: Warning: Remapping private port 80 to 82 in role 'MvcApplication' to avoid conflict during emulation.
Windows Azure Tools: Warning: Remapping private port 443 to 446 in role 'MvcApplication' to avoid conflict during emulation.
```

So emulator registered his load-balancing endpoint on public port 81\444 and exposed some kind of internal endpoint on 82\446.
But I suspect that '127.0.0.1' and 'localhost' behave a bit differently (I know that it's the same thing, just suspect that IP url will go through a bit different pipeline, but I can't confirm my guesses) and, especially if you have multiple sites in one role - 127.0.0.1 won't be able to hit proper endpoint (maybe cause it's doesn't contain proper host header? ).

This leads to the situation when localhost:444 (in our case) work correctly and 127.0.0.1:444 don't.

[This answer also could lead you to some options how to fix\deal with that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272013/windows-8-azure-emulator-is-remapping-port-80-to-81)

Hope it'll help you a bit